# How to reset all states of ngrx/store?

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx

I am using Angular 2 with [ngrx/store](https://github.com/ngrx/store). I want to reset the whole store states when user dispatch `USER_LOGOUT`.

I read the Dan Abramov's answer of [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store), but I didn't figure out how to write `rootReducer` correctly and where to put it when using ngrx/store.

Or is there any other way to handle this in ngrx/store?

```
bootstrap(App, [
    provideStore(
      compose(
        storeFreeze,
        storeLogger(),
        combineReducers
      )({
        router: routerReducer,
        foo: fooReducer,
        bar: barReducer
      })
    )
  ]);
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This answer is specific to ngrx version 2. The question has [another, more recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45324038/6680611) that explains how the same can be done with ngrx version 4.

---

`compose` builds the ngrx **root reducer**.

The arguments passed to `compose` are functions that return a reducer - composed from the reducer they themselves are passed as an argument. You can compose the resetting of your store like this:

```
import { compose } from "@ngrx/core/compose";

...

bootstrap(App, [
  provideStore(
    compose(
      storeFreeze,
      storeLogger(),
      (reducer: Function) => {
        return function(state, action) {
          if (action.type === 'USER_LOGOUT') {
            state = undefined;
          }
          return reducer(state, action);
        };
      },
      combineReducers
    )({
      router: routerReducer,
      foo: fooReducer,
      bar: barReducer
    })
  )
]);
```

Note that this will reset all of the store's state - including the `router`. If that's not what you want, you could tweak the example.

With introduction of `NgModule` the bootstrapping has changed, but you still pass the composed reducer to `provideStore`:

```
import { compose } from "@ngrx/core/compose";
import { StoreModule } from "@ngrx/store";

@NgModule({
    ...
    imports: [
        ...
        StoreModule.provideStore(compose(...))
    ],
    ...
```

Comment: How would I do this in the current version of ngrx?

Comment: @Daskus You pass the composed reducer to `StoreModule.provideStore`. See the updated answer.

Comment: @cartant how to do this on latest ngrx version using `forRoot` and `forFeature`? I'm following you on angularindepth.com, I would appreciate an article on this.

Comment: @AndreaM16 See the answer from David Bulté, below.

Answer (score 48):

In ngrx/store 4.x, this can be accomplished with [Meta-reducers](https://ngrx.io/guide/store/metareducers). As I understand it, all actions are passing through the metareducers before being handed over to the feature reducers. This gives us the opportunity to change/reset the state first.

Here's an example.

This is my metareducer function: in case the action is of type LOGOUT, the state is re-initialized.

```
function logout(reducer) {
  return function (state, action) {
    return reducer(action.type === LOGOUT ? undefined : state, action);
  }
}
```

Below you see how the metareducer is configured along with the feature reducers. Should there be more than 1 metareducer, then they are evaluated from right to left

```
StoreModule.forRoot({rooms: roomReducer, user: userReducer}, {metaReducers: [logout]})
```

Finally, I also have an @effect where I navigate to the login page

```
@Effect({dispatch: false}) logout: Observable<Action> = 
this.actions$.ofType(LOGOUT)
  .do(() => {
    // ... some more stuff here ...
    this.router.navigate(['/login page'])
});
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as for now 4.x has some changes.

Comment: This is still perfectly valid with Angular 8 and Ngrx-8.

Answer (score 15):

With @ngrx/store": "^4.0.3" this is slightly different because there are small changes, so my 'clear state' looks like this

```
import { ActionReducerMap } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

export const rootReducer: ActionReducerMap<StoreStates> = {
  points: pointsReducer,
  ...
};

export function clearState(reducer: ActionReducer<StoreStates>): ActionReducer<StoreStates> {
  return function(state: StoreStates, action: Action): StoreStates {
    if (action.type === 'CLEAR_STATE') {
      state = undefined;
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}
export const metaReducers: MetaReducer<StoreStates>[] = [clearState];
```

and

```
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { metaReducers, rootReducer } from '../root.reducer';

export const imports: any = [
   StoreModule.forRoot(rootReducer, { metaReducers }),
   ...
]
```

Comment: How is this going to work when the app is organized into modules (with lazy loading), and each of the module has its own feature state?

Comment: It works with lazy loading as well, I mean I've got all my feature module lazy loading but the service and the store are in a shared module that I put in the app module

Comment: BTW the CLEAR_STATE action in my case is LOGOUT ACTION)

Answer (score 3):

This isn't really an answer but the comments won't let me format it correctly.   To add to what cartant said, if you are setting up your types like this:

```
export const ActionTypes = {
  LOGOUT:  type('[Environment] Logout of portal'),
  ....
}
```

It's the long description that you should use.  Also if you name your root reducer `rootReducer` instead of just `reducer` then you would change that as well.  Following is an edited example:

(I left this function within my root reducer)

```
const developmentReducer: ActionReducer<State> = compose(...DEV_REDUCERS,
(rootReducer: Function) => {
    return function(state, action) {
      if (action.type === '[Environment] Logout of portal') {
        state = undefined;
      }
      return rootReducer(state, action);
    };
  }, combineReducers)(reducers);
```

Comment: How do you do this with productionReducer?

Answer (score 0):

[UPDATE 2022]

This blog post works like a charm for Angular 14 and very easy to implement. You can use any action to reset store. https://www.purcellyoon.com/insights/articles/angular-ngrx-8-reset-state-using-meta-reducer

Define logout action in actions.ts

```
import { createAction, props } from '@ngrx/store';

export const logoutSuccess = createAction('[Authentication] Logout Success');
```

Define your MetaReducer in reducers.ts

```
import { ActionReducer, ActionReducerMap, INIT, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';

import * as AuthActions from './actions';

export const reducers: ActionReducerMap<State> = {
    [featureKey1]: reducer1,
    [featureKey2]: reducer2,
    //...

    }

export const logout = (reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> => {
  return (state, action) => {
    if (action !== null && action.type === AuthActions.logoutSuccess.type) {
      return reducer(undefined, { type: INIT });
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
};

export const metaReducers: MetaReducer[] = [logout];
```

app.store.module.ts

```
import { metaReducers, reducers } from '../store/reducers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: true,
        strictActionImmutability: true
      }
    }),
```

Now dispatch your action in the component

```
this.store.dispatch(logout());
```

In effects, dispatch logout success action so that the user logs out and the store is reset.

```
logout$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
      ofType(Actions.logout),
      mergeMap((action) =>
        this.apiService.logout().pipe(
          map((user: User) => Actions.logoutSuccess()),
          catchError((error) => of(Actions.logoutFailure({ error })))
        )
      )
    ));
```

Comment: This code is so incomplete it doesn't really help. Your reducer is named 'logout', and then you dispatch that reducer instead of some action? Just a confusing mess.