# NGRX - What is the best way to reset the entire state?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

What is the best way to reset the entire state when we have different reducers?
I am having problems with this when I use selectors, since it does not bring me the initial state when I do the reset

MetaReducer

```
import { ActionReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
import { UserActionTypes } from '../../actions/actionTypes';

export function clearStateReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === UserActionTypes.Logout) {
      state = undefined;
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}
```

State Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { StateService } from './state.service';
import { StoreDevtoolsModule } from '@ngrx/store-devtools';
import { StoreModule } from '@ngrx/store';
import { appReducer } from './reducers';
import { getInitialState } from './state';
import { metaReducers } from './reducers/metaReducers';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    StoreModule.forRoot(appReducer, {
      initialState: getInitialState(),
      metaReducers,
      runtimeChecks: {
        strictStateImmutability: false,
        strictActionImmutability: false,
        strictStateSerializability: false,
        strictActionSerializability: false
      }
    }),
    StoreDevtoolsModule.instrument({
      maxAge: 25
    })
  ],
  providers: [StateService]
})
export class StateServiceModule {}
```

Comment: What is your current approach?

Comment: Refreshing the page will start the app with initial ngrx state.
Other than that you probably want to use meta-reducer.
Third option is to add a new action and new case for each reducer and trigger them all from resetState$ effect.

Comment: Can you share your code in stackblitz? Are you using localstorage ?

Comment: Im using this metaReducer - export function clearStateReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === UserActionTypes.Logout) {
      state = undefined;
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}

Comment: @Jose So what's the problem then - it should reset the whole state.

Comment: More explanations about how to do it using meta-reducer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323285/how-to-reset-all-states-of-ngrx-store and here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39323285/how-to-reset-all-states-of-ngrx-store/45324038#45324038

Comment: The problem is that after resetting, when I call a selector it returns the value before the reset

Comment: @Jose if you can confirm that the state is really reset, but you are still getting the previous state when using selectors, it's because the selectors are memoized (they store the result of the previous call in cache, so if you pass the same params, the memoized function doesn't run the computation but returns the computed result stored in its cache). There is a way to reset ngrx selectors by running `selectorName.release()`. More about that on https://ngrx.io/guide/store/selectors#resetting-memoized-selectors

Comment: Perfect @codeepic when should i use it then? Sorry but im new in ngrx

Comment: This I don't know for sure and the docs are lacking. But selectors are just functions, you usually use them either in effects or in components, when subscribing to pieces of state inside `state.pipe(...` method. But you should be able to use them anywhere. In that case I would call `.release()` method on each selector from inside `if (action.type === UserActionTypes.Logout) {` check in your meta reducer. Do let me know if it solves the issue for you.

Comment: Unfortunately not, perhaps it is an error of the release method, since it does not reset me of any selector regardless of where I use it, equally thanks!

Comment: OK, thanks for the update and sorry to hear it's not working for you - open a github issue then under ngrx OS project.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset like this by setting the state back to the initial state

```
export const postReducer = createReducer(
  initialState,
  on(PostActions.ResetState, (state) => {
    return { state: initialState };
  }),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not assign state, instead call the reducer with `undefined`:

```
export function clearStateReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
  return (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === UserActionTypes.Logout) {
      return reducer(undefined, action);
    }
    return reducer(state, action);
  };
}
```