# Redux changing my initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my reducer for a snake game I'm making. Basically, whenever I want to reset the game, I update the state to `INITIAL_STATE` as seen in `NEW_GAME`, but whenever `MOVE_SNAKE` fires, it seems to be modifying `INITIAL_STATE`, so I'm basically passing it the current state and `NEW_GAME` does nothing.

I added that `console.log(INITIAL_STATE.coords[0])` to confirm, and any time the snake moves, the `INITIAL_STATE` updates to the current state too. Why is this? I've done something similar like this in a tic tac toe game, but now it's not working?

```
// REDUCER

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    coords: [
        [1, 0],
        [1, 1],
        [1, 2]
    ]
};

export default function(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    console.log(INITIAL_STATE.coords[0]);
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'MOVE_SNAKE':
            return {
                ...state,
                coords: action.coords
            }

        case 'NEW_GAME':
            return INITIAL_STATE;
    }

    return state;
}

// ACTION CREATORS

export function moveSnake(snake) {
    let { coords, direction } = snake;
    let headCoords = coords[coords.length-1];
    let newHead = () => {
        if(direction === 'DOWN') return [headCoords[0], headCoords[1]+1];
        if(direction === 'UP') return [headCoords[0], headCoords[1]-1];
        if(direction === 'LEFT') return [headCoords[0]-1, headCoords[1]];
        if(direction === 'RIGHT') return [headCoords[0]+1, headCoords[1]];
    };
    coords.push(newHead());
    coords.shift();

    return {
        type: 'MOVE_SNAKE',
        coords
    }
}

// COMPONENT CALL LOOKS LIKE THIS

this.props.moveSnake(this.props.snake);
```

I've tried using `Object.assign()` on everything, and it still was messing with my `INITIAL_STATE`.

Comment: Can you paste any other code that uses this state, like action creators and selectors?  How do you put together the new coords for the `MOVE_SNAKE` action?

Comment: @markerikson added the action creator and the call!

Comment: Here is the answer by one of the creators of redux(Dan Abramov) : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your mutating the state, `Object.assign()` is good, but when working with arrays you should use `concat`, `slice` and `filter`!

Let's say you have an array

```
let a = {name:"bob", things: [1,2,4]}
let b = Object.assign({}, a, {name: "joe"})
```

In the example above you might be thinking that `b` is independent from `a`, but if we do something like `b.things.push(3)`, you'll see that `a.things` changed!!
To stop this, make sure you're using `slice` like this `b.things = a.things.slice()`. Hope this cleared it out ;)

Now, you're code is kinda hard to figure it out, but you know where you're working with and assigning arrays, so make sure you're using `slice()` as well, not only `Object.assign()`.

Comment: I NEVER KNEW THAT! It works now, thank you! I should really start using Immutable or something.

Comment: Wow, amazing to hear this! This is the video that helped me understand it https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9M-r8p9ey8U

Comment: Yup, as I figured.  You should read the ["Structuring Reducers"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/StructuringReducers.html) section of the Redux docs for more info, especially ["Prerequisite Concepts"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/PrerequisiteConcepts.html) and ["Immutable Update Patterns"](http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html).