# Reset the store to it's initial state on receiving a specific action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

When a user logs out, I want to reset the entire store to it's initial state. I want to do this because I don't want to store any items in memory after they lost the authentication context.

I think this makes the most sense to be implemented as a middleware, so I started as follows

```
import { LOGOUT } from 'app/actions/auth';

export default function authMiddleware(store) {
  return action => next => {
    if (action.type === LOGOUT) {
      // ???
    }
    next();
  }
}
```

Specifically, I am having a hard time finding the initial state of the store on the initial instantiation of the application.

Is there a standard way to do this in redux?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store

Comment: You should create a `initialState` variable and return that when the action is `logout`. You can also assign `store = initialState` in the function parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can set that to the initial state by declaring a variable as

```
const initialState = {};
```

And then if the case matches you can return the `initialState`