# Apollo graphql-connected React component isn't rerendering

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, apollo-client

I'm working on building an authentication mechanism over graphql, and I'm trying to figure out why a graphql-connected component isn't rerendering after relogin... for example:

- At `/users` I have a react-apollo graphql-connected Users component that requests a list of users.
- The server will return an authentication error if no token is provided; the component renders a `<Redirect>` to the `/login` route; after successful login, the Login component stashes the token and redirects back.
- The Users component wrapper starts the graphql request and renders "loading..." in the meantime. When the graphql request succeeds, it rerenders and the users appear, yay.
- If you Sign Out from that page, the Logout component at `/logout` discards the token then redirects back; the Users component's request gets the authentication error again and sends you to '/login'.
- After another successful login, you're sent back to '/users'; again it starts a graphql request to the server (and renders "loading..."), but this time, when the request succeeds, the component isn't updated again.

I can see that the graphql request succeeds (and have watched in Chrome's debugger as the APOLLO_QUERY_RESULT action is handled by react-apollo's reducer and updates the state in the store).

I've tried to find where React is checking to see if the component's props have changed, but I'm enough of a React debugging noob that I haven't figured out where to find that code in the web inspector: maybe something I don't understand about how React is packaged for distribution.

I clear out the ApolloClient's store (by calling `resetStore()`) on both login and logout, since I don't want to accidentally reuse data from the other authenticatedness; however, removing these calls doesn't get rid of the problem. Interestingly (?), if I force the connection to bypass the cache by providing `{ options: { fetchPolicy: 'network-only' } }` in the `graphql()` call, the problem goes away. (Not a viable solution - I'd like to benefit from the cache generally.)

I've built a stripped-down example: https://github.com/bryanstearns/apollo-auth-experiment
and you can see it in a CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/m4nlpp86j (you'll probably want to access the running example from an independent browser window at https://m4nlpp86j.codesandbox.io/ because the sandbox editor kinda makes the web debug extensions act weird).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To fix this behavior, modify your graphql HOC to include `notifyOnNetworkStatusChange` in the options.

```
export const Users = graphql(usersQuery, { options: { notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true } })(RawUsers);
```

I don't think you should *have* to do that -- I think `data.loading` is supposed to accurately reflect the status of your query regardless of that option being set to true, unlike `data.networkStatus` but it [looks like it's a known bug](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-client/issues/1186).

As far as `resetStore` -- it doesn't actually wipe your entire store, but rather wipes away your store **and** refetches all your active queries. If you wanted to blow away your store, since you're already integrating Redux with Apollo, the easiest thing to do would be to [create an action to do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store).

You may also want to consider a session-based authentication mechanism, rather than relying on the client to persist a token. It's pretty simple to implement server-side, would not only involve less work on the client-side (don't have to remember to pass the token in with every request), and would let you keep your user logged in after they navigate away from the page.

Comment: Excellent, Daniel, thanks - that fixes my problem, and reading the history of the issue you linked to was... educational :-). I might switch to cookie authentication; this was also my first experiment with localStorage. Tokens do have the advantage that they work across multiple domains (though that's not a problem I have yet) and Apollo makes it easy to globally configure for all requests: https://github.com/bryanstearns/apollo-auth-experiment/blob/ac05f47ace4fe00f346cbacde8d342306b6b94e0/src/index.js#L31