# Handling loading state in a React app that uses Redux with redux-thunk, going back to component after data has been fetched once

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a React app that uses Redux with `redux-thunk`. Given a certain component that needs to fetch information from an API, I call a bound action creator to make that request after it mounts:

```
componentDidMount() {
  this.props.fetchSomething();
}
```

For the UI to know whether it is in a loading state, I use a `loading` variable from the application state. My reducer handles three action types for `LOADING`, `SUCCESS`, and `FAILURE`. The `loading` variable is set to `true` when the `LOADING` action is emitted; then it is set to `false` on `SUCCESS` and `FAILURE`.

Thus there is the following in the `render` method:

```
render() {
  if (this.props.loading) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      This part uses the fetched data, available via this.props.something
    </div>
  );
}
```

Because initially `this.props.something` is `null`, I also have to check for its existence before rendering the desired template, so the above if-statement becomes:

```
if (!this.props.something || this.props.loading) {
  return <Spinner />;
}
```

This approach has served me well so far, but there are some issues, one of them being:

> The first time I access the page, `this.props.something` is not yet set. But the second time I access the page, with the app already loaded, that data had already been fetched once, so `this.props.something` will have been defined. Because of that, there is brief moment in which the if statement condition is FALSE and the actual component template gets rendered.

(1) How would you guys take care of that issue?

(2) And with your approach, how would you handle a component that had to make multiple requests, like five of them, using the same approach above, with a different `loading`/`something` variable for each? I can duplicate the same approach above, but get the issue of brief if-statement failure for each resource that is already defined, but not loading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You have two options. U can dispatch some `RESET` action on `componentWillUnmount` and reset your store, `this.props.something` will be null again. Second option is to show data if u already have them, show spinner and when second fetch is success merge it together. (depends on purpose and UI)

2) I have never needed it but what about to store it in  redux as map {componentName: loaded} and check if all components are loaded?

Edit: When u set initial value of `loading` to true you don't need to check something prop.

Comment: a) I had loading set to false by default. I think initializing it to true is something to think about. b) I used to use componentWillMount for http requests, but then stopped using it and now use componentDidMount, because I was told / read somewhere that was the best practice. It would be nice to have someone confirm that. c) Regarding (1), I could do that, but I use reducer composition and the multiple resources are split between different subreducers. In that case, I would have to make a reset for each?

Comment: The issue I am trying to solve has to do with the spinner. The brief moments when each resource is already set, but not loading causes the if statement in the render to skip rendering the Spinner and going all the way through. That is barely seen by the end user, but the spinner clearly goes back to its initial animation state, it looks weird.

Comment: a) i call it `loaded` to make it logically sense b) sorry `componentDidMount` is better, explanation: [where-fetch-data](https://daveceddia.com/where-fetch-data-componentwillmount-vs-componentdidmount/) c) here is example how to reset state after logout: [how-to-reset-the-state](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store)

Comment: To the issue what about to not handle spinner on the top level, but in children components and instead of spinner use some kind of preloaders? (e.g. empty div with approx same size, so user will see approximate layout)

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I ended up calling many action creators to reset the resource variable to null in componentWillUnmount. I found that was the best approach for what I was trying to do. As for handling the spinner in the children, that sounds like a good approach too, but my specification needs the whole page to be under the spinner.