# How to clear all states in redux store when user logs out?

Tags: reactjs, redux, store

If not clear all states, the dirty datas may be rendered to the components when a new user logs in, Obviously it's a bug. I find a simple solution that reloads the page when the route jumps to '/#/login' after a click on logout button. Is anyone have a more elegant solution? Thanks.

Comment: I have read that link, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Why is it not working ?

Comment: Thank you for reminding me，[How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store) can solve my problem, other mistake make me fail, thanks again!