# Save Edits to redux state that can easily be undone

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a redux state holding various keys and values:

```html
data: {
  item1: {
    id: 1
    name: 'Shirt',
    cost: 3
  },
  item2: {
    id: 2
    name: 'Pants',
    cost: 10
  },
  item3: {
    id: 3
    name: 'Hat',
    cost: 7
  }
}
```

I have an interface where the user can change these values.  I want them to be able to make any number of changes to this data and if they want to go back to the original state, they can hit a reset button.

**How would you go about structuring the redux state to hold the edit information?**

What I'm imagining is simply starting with the original state, and then duplicating the original state.  So I'd have `originalMenu` and `editedMenu` in the redux state.  That way any deletions, inserts, edits, etc. will be contained to the `editedMenu` part of the state.

The above doesn't seem very clean because I'd need to store duplicate data in the redux state.  I was also imagining having a `menuEdits` part of the state that just houses the changes.  So it'd have the `id` and whatever values have been changed.  Or an `isDeleted` field for removed items.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should have three states in your data object: past, present and future. Can you check this https://github.com/reactjs/redux/blob/master/docs/recipes/ImplementingUndoHistory.md out?.I think it may be helpful.

Comment: This is really helpful, thank you. I hadn't considered doing this but I love the idea.  Lucky all the editable data in my state is in the same area.

Comment: Hi, is there any update for this repo/ answer? The link now leads to a 404.

Comment: @Maiya https://redux.js.org/usage/implementing-undo-history