# why after refresh page state is undefined?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

```js
//routes
const AppRoute = () => {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div className="container">
          <Switch>
            <Route path='/' component={BooksList} exact/>
            <Route path='/create' component={BookCreate}/>
            <Route path='/books/:id' component={BookShow}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
};
export default AppRoute;

//store 
const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(Promise));
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <AppRoute/>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

I use react and redux.
I created a BookShow component to show data of one book. Data loads correctly but when I refresh the page I get this error:
Type Error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined and hole state is undefined.

Why did this happen and how can I prevent it from happening?
this is my code

```js
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

const BookShow = props => {
  if(!props){
    return <div>loading...</div>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h2 className="text-center">{props.book.title}</h2>
      <p className="">{props.book.body}</p>
      {console.log(props)}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    book: state.books.find((book) => {
      return book.id === props.match.params.id
    })
  }
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookShow);
```

Comment: Could you please add the relevant code of your routes and the initialization of your redux store?

Comment: const AppRoute = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <div className="container">
        <Switch>
          <Route path='/' component={BooksList} exact/>
          <Route path='/create' component={BookCreate}/>
          <Route path='/books/:id' component={BookShow}/>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};
export default AppRoute;

Comment: You can edit your question. Please add the code there as it is very hard to read otherwise.

Comment: sorry for that i edit my post

Comment: How do you initialy load books to store? and sometimes when using connect you need to use withRouter from react-router-dom to be able to use match,history,location etc.

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store/35641992#35641992, once you refresh your redux store is populated with the initialState

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested it though! Try it and let me know.

```
import React from 'react';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'

    class BookShow extends React.Component{
        constructor(props, context) {
            super(props, context);
            this.state = {
                book: {}
            }
        }


        componentWillMount(){
            const { match: { params }, books } = this.props;
            this.state.book = books.find((book) => {
                return book.id === params.id
            });
        }

        render(){
            const { book } = this.props;

            if(!props){
                return <div>loading...</div>
            }

            return (
                <div>
                  <h2 className="text-center">{book.title}</h2>
                  <p className="">{book.body}</p>
                </div>
              );
        }

    }

    const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
      return {
        books: state.books
      }
    };
    export default connect(mapStateToProps)(BookShow);
```

Answer (score 0):

BookShow is a stateless component, try to make it a class,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class BookShow extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
your code...
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: how does converting to a class help?

Comment: reactjs got two type of components, one is components using state which we use class and other one is stateless components, we cant use state in a state less component.

Answer (score 0):

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps)(BookShow));
```

when you start from homePage and then navigate to some book you can use `props.match.params.id` but when refreshing page you can't. Try to use `withRouter` to see if it will fix your problem.