# Reset the state of a Redux store except a few values?

Tags: react-redux

I want to reset the state of the redux store on logout without removing some values. 
I referred to this link : [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store/35641992).
How can i keep some values intact in the store after logout.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/5058312) answer can be slightly modified to suit your case.

Instead of setting `state = undefined;` completely, you can use merge() methods to clear only specific properties while retaining the others.

```
     const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
      if (action.type === 'USER_LOGOUT') {
        return state.merge({
            value1: undefined,
            value2: undefined,
            ...
        });
      }

      return appReducer(state, action)
    }
```