# How can I restart my initialState values in Redux

Tags: redux, react-redux, react-native

Hello everyone im new using redux in my react-native app. well I saved a bad information within my InitialState of the nav so when I try to reload the application in the android emulator I get this error

> Invariant Vilation: There is no route defined for key User. Must be one of: 'Main', 'Welcome'

[image]

The error happened because in this method

## actions/user.js

```
export function loginWithFacebook(facebookAccessToken) {
return (dispatch) => {
return fetch(`${HOST}/api/v1/facebook`, {
  method: 'POST',
  body: JSON.stringify({
    facebook_access_token: facebookAccessToken,
  }),
  headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
})
.then(response => response.json())
.then(json => {
  console.log(json);

  if (json.access_token) {
    dispatch(setAccessToken(json.access_token));
    dispatch(setProfile(normalizeProfile(json.email, json.fullname, json.image)));
    dispatch(resetRoute({ routeName: 'Welcome' }));
  } else {
    alert(json.error);
  }
})
.catch(e => alert(e)); }; }
```

The error happened in this line

> dispatch(resetRoute({ routeName: 'Welcome' }));

### I Wrote "Home" instead "Welcome"

> and the value Home was added to my initialState nav instead Welcome value

## actions/nav.js

```
export function resetRoute(route) {
return (dispatch, getState) => {
const nav = getState().nav;
dispatch(NavigationActions.reset({
  index: 0,
  key: null,
  actions: [
    NavigationActions.navigate(route)
  ]
})); }; }
```

## Reducers

### index.js

```
export default combineReducers({
nav,
user });
```

### nav.js

```
const initialState =        AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(NavigationActions.reset({
index: 0,
actions: [
  NavigationActions.navigate({
    routeName: 'Main',
  }),
], }));

export default function(state = initialState, action) {
  //state = undefined;
  const nextState = AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action,    state);
  return nextState || state;
};
```

> above method throws the exceptions because when it calls AppNavigator.router.getStateForAction(action, state); it gets "Home" instead "Welcome" so basically I need to restart the initialState to the beginning

How can I set null all my initialState reducers MANUALLY? remember I can not see a screen in my android emulator so I can not fire actions with buttons or something similar.

I found this article: [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store) but in my case I can not see the screen to fire the Logout action.

> The solution I think is to set null or empty my initialState value of my reducers to can start from the beginning. but how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

So your main problem is that you want to reset the state of the store, but you cannot even access the first screen, so you cannot dispatch an action in a screen to reset it, am I right?

What you may be able to do, together with the other stackoverflow answer that you linked: [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store), you may be able to reset the state before a screen is rendered.

If you have your reducers as it's mentioned there, you can dispatch an action **before** a screen is rendered. For example, in the index of your application. You may want to do it in the index file, for example.

You can achieve this by not using `react-redux` but dispatching an action directly to the store by using the [dispatch](https://redux.js.org/api-reference/store#dispatch-action) method.

Something like `store.dispatch(<Reseting action goes here>)` in your index file, before you actually render any screen.

Hope it helps! Let me know if you find any more problems or if it's not clear enough. Cheers!