# how to reset redux store when log out?

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am trying to reset my storage when I log out but it doesn't seem to work at all.

As you can see I am using AsyncStorage for my store and I try to follow the answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store) post.

Here is my index.js from store folder

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { createStore, compose, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import { persistStore, autoRehydrate } from 'redux-persist';
import rootReducer from '../reducers';

var defaultState = {};

export function configureStore(initialState = defaultState) {
  var store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    autoRehydrate(),
  ));
  persistStore(store, { storage: AsyncStorage });
  return store;
}
```

and here is my index.js from reducers folder

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

import authReducer from './authReducer';
import alertsReducer from './alertsReducer';
import jobsReducer from './jobsReducer';
import userDataReducer from './userDataReducer';

const appReducer = combineReducers({
  form: formReducer,
  auth: authReducer,
  alerts: alertsReducer,
  jobs: jobsReducer,
  userData: userDataReducer
})

const rootReducer = ( state, action ) => {
  if(action.type === 'UNAUTH_USER') {
    Object.keys(state).forEach(key => {
      AsyncStorage.removeItem(`persist:${key}`);
      console.log(state)
    });
  }
  return appReducer(state, action)
}

export default rootReducer
```

Answer (score 1):

On **Initial load** of our application the reducer state is **fresh**.

We Can copy this initial default state and use it to assign to our reducer again on logging out, the way we can achieve this could be as follows.

Step 1: call an action on the application load that will copy reducer's initial state as the **defaultState**

Step 2: While logging out of the application we can simply **reAssign** the **default state** and it should work as **new**.

**App root Component**

```
  componentDidMount() {   
    dispatch(ON_APP_LOAD)
  }
```

**App Reducer**

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  user: userStatusReducer,     
  analysis: analysisReducer,
  incentives: incentivesReducer
});

let defaultState = null;
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case **ON_APP_LOAD**:
      // will be assigned or called only once 
      defaultState = defaultState || state;
      break;
    case **RESET_STATE**:
      // detaching the reference on reset
      state = _.deepClone(defaultState);
      return state;
    default:
      break;
  }
  return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

**On Logout calling the action for resetting state**

```
function* logoutUser(action) {
  // on logout success 
  dispatch("RESET_STATE")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have the js file where all reducers are combined in one and thus you have:

```
const allReducers = combineReducers({
   reducer: nameOfReducer
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {

    switch (action.type) {
        case  CLEAR_ALL_REDUCERS_DATA:
            return state = undefined;
        default:
            return allReducers(state, action)
    }
};

export default rootReducer;
```

and in index file where you create a store you need to define

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer,
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
);
```

and then simply call it on logout:

```
dispatch(clearAllStoreData());
```

where clearAllStoreData is an action defined in your action file:

```
export const clearAllStoreData = () => {
    return {
        type: CLEAR_ALL_REDUCERS_DATA
    }
};
```