# how to initialise all states when press reset button in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, reduce, redux-thunk

in my app i'm using `redux` with `redux-thunk`.there is on **RESET** Button, when user click it i want `INITIALIZE` all redux state instead of `window.location.reload()`.
**index.js** *(reducers index file)*

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from "redux-form";
import authReducer from './auth_reducer';
import main from './main'
import BookingData from './booking_reducer';
import StepOne from './stepone';
import StepTwo from './stepTwo'

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    form: reduxFormReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    Main:main,
    StepOneReducer:StepOne,
    StepTwoReducer:StepTwo,
    BookingData:BookingData,

})

export default rootReducer;
```

here each value of object contains **separate reducer file** and each reducer file has **number of states**
**App.js** *(root file)*

```
import ReactDOM     from "react-dom";
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import reducers from './reducers';
const middleware = [
    reduxThunk,
];

const store = createStore(reducers, composeWithDevTools(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
// other store enhancers if any
));



const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if(token){
    store.dispatch({type:AUTH_USER});
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
        <AppRouter />
    </Provider>
    , document.getElementById('app'));
```

so my problem is when press **Reset Button** it will call `action Creator`, it will dispatch the action when it comes to the reducer(index reducer) I'm unable reset all state.
**i saw [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store) also but here i don't want to change my index reducer file structure because I need export both and project logic also get mess.**
***how can i initialize all redux state when user click Reset Button***

Comment: In 'reset all state', do you mean to initialize the state in all of the reducers?

Comment: @Rahamin yeah, want to initialize same default  redux state

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, then I am doing a similar thing in my apps:

I reset my entire redux state by dispatching a 'reset', or 'initialize' action, and have a case in all reducers for this action, where I set the state to the initial values.

Comment: haha,right now i'm also doing same thing but here is [proper](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store) way, so want solve using that method.

Comment: Well, wasn't aware of that... I will stay with my way, though :)

Answer (score 0):

actually i was exporting `AppReducer` instead of `rootReducer`

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as reduxFormReducer } from "redux-form";
import authReducer from './auth_reducer';
import main from './main'
import BookingData from './booking_reducer';
import StepOne from './stepone';
import StepTwo from './stepTwo'
import {RESET} from '../actions/types';
const AppReducer = combineReducers({
    form: reduxFormReducer,
    auth: authReducer,
    Main:main,
    StepOneReducer:StepOne,
    StepTwoReducer:StepTwo,
    BookingData:BookingData,

})

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === RESET) {
        console.log('reset action inside root');
        state = undefined
    }

    return AppReducer(state, action)
}

export default rootReducer;
```

worked [Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/9623598) solution