# Resetting redux state on logout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-redux

I am trying to deal with the problem, addressed, in general in an earlier thread - [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store) - the need to reinitialize/invalidate the entire redux store on user logout.

In my case, however, something is still missing. I am using Redux with ConnectedRouter and I tried to do the following.

Define the rootReducer as:

```
export default history => 
  combineReducers({
    router: connectRouter(history),
    user,
    manager,
    vendor
    // rest of your reducers
  });
```

Then I do `configureStore`, importing the above  as `createRootReducer`:

```
const configureStore = (initialState = {}, history) => {
  let composeEnhancers = compose;
  const composeWithDevToolsExtension =
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__;
  const enhancers = [];
  const middleware = [sagaMiddleware, thunk, routerMiddleware(history)];
  if (typeof composeWithDevToolsExtension === 'function') {
    composeEnhancers = composeWithDevToolsExtension;
  }
  const store = createStore(
    createRootReducer(history), // root reducer with router state
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
  );
  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  store.subscribe(() => {
    const state = store.getState();
    const { session } = state['user'];
    if (!session) {
      console.log('no valid session');
      initialState = undefined;
    } else {
      const { token } = session;
      const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token);
      const { exp } = decodedToken;
      const now = new Date();
      if (exp > now.getTime()) {
        console.warn('token expired');
        initialState = undefined;
      } else {
        console.log('token valid');
      }
    }
  });
  return store;
};
export default configureStore({}, history);
```

The idea is that `initialState = undefined;` should reset my state. It is not working for me though.

Where would be the correct place to do this, given that I am using the `ConnectedRouter` and passing the `history` object to it?

Comment: have you tried dispatching an action to the reducer to set the state undefined and then logout ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I wanted to point out to a couple of things that are pretty important before I give you a solution:

1. When using redux you should never attempt to alter the state of your store directly. The state should always change through the reducer as a reaction to an action. Therefore, reassigning the parameter `initialState` inside that `subscribe` callback is incorrect and pointless.
2. I don't think that you want to "reset" the state of the `router` property, correct?

One way to solve this is to use a reducer enhancer, something like this:

```
const resetEnhancer = rootReducer => (state, action) => {
  if (action.type !== 'RESET') return rootReducer(state, action);

  const newState = rootReducer(undefined, {});
  newState.router = state.router;
  return newState;
};
```

And then when you create your store do this:

```
  const store = createStore(
    resetEnhancer(createRootReducer(history)),
    initialState,
    composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(...middleware), ...enhancers)
  );
```

And in that `subscribe` callback do this:

```
if (!session) {
  store.dispatch({type: 'RESET'});
}
```

One last extra-tip: since you are using `redux-saga` I strongly suggest that you move what you are doing inside that `subscribe` callback into a saga.

Comment: while your solution does not work, as is, even after we add the missing `)` around `resetEnhancer`, I do think that your thinking is correct. Thank you. Definitely looks like the correct general direction. The state does not reset, though. ;(

I will keep playing with what you gave me. Appreciate the help.

Comment: @MosheShmukler I just updated my answer... There were 2 things that were wrong: the closing parenthesis around `resetEnhancer` and the fact that inside the `resetEnhancer` I was doing  `action !== 'RESET'` instead of `action.type !== 'RESET'`. Try changing those 2 and I'm pretty sure that it will work :)

Comment: got it working. Your version was 99% correct, and the idea was totally right.```
  const resetEnhancer = rootReducer => (state, action) => {
    if (action.type !== 'LOGOUT_USER') {
      return rootReducer(state, action);
    }
    const newState = rootReducer(undefined, { type: 'LOGOUT_USER' });
    newState.router = state.router;
    return newState;
  };```

Comment: what is the `createRootReducer(history)` and where it came from?

Comment: @TheCoder it is explained in the OPs question. It is the first snipped of code that appears in the question. Also, just after that snipped the OP says: "Then I do configureStore, importing the above as createRootReducer"

Comment: how to create a action type of name 'RESET' in redux toolkit , please suggest some ideas @Josep or anyone

Answer (score 1):

You can make an action for clearing the store and use it in your `rootReducer` as like this:

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
    ... // your reducers
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === 'CLEAR_STORE') return appReducer(undefined, action);
    return appReducer(state, action);
};

const composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
export const configureStore = (initialState, history) =>
    createStore(
        connectRouter(history)(rootReducer),
        initialState,
        composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(routerMiddleware(history), thunkMiddleware))
    );
```

You'll have `appReducer` with all your reducers but also `rootReducer` which will be the function that will determinate returning a corresponding value or an undefined one.

> **TIP:** You can use your Logout action rather than using a new action just for clearing the store

Comment: Unfortunately what you are suggesting will also reinitialise the `router` property and I think that the OP is looking for a solution where `router` property is not updated. Apart from that, your solution is quite similar to mine :)