# How to clear your store

Tags: reactjs, redux

before post i tried to read the super-answer of Dan Abramov in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store/35641992#35641992)

I have a little problem in my code, i will be happy to understand my mistake:

1) this is my index file

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';

import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import appReducer from './appReducer';
import errorReducer from './errorReducer';
import loginReducer from './loginReducer';
import modalReducer from './modalReducer';
import changeRequestReducer from './changeRequestReducer';
import releaseReducer from './releaseReducer';
import releaseReviewReducer from './releaseReviewReducer';
import logoutReducer from './logoutReducer';
import customAvatarReducer from './customAvatarReducer';


    export default combineReducers({
      appReducer,
      errorReducer,
      loginReducer,
      changeRequestReducer,
      releaseReducer,
      modalReducer,
      releaseReviewReducer,
      form: formReducer,
      logoutReducer,
      customAvatarReducer,
    });
```

I tried to add this:

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === USER_LOGOUT) {
    const state = undefined;
  }

  return reducers(state, action);
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
  appReducer,
  errorReducer,
  loginReducer,
  changeRequestReducer,
  releaseReducer,
  modalReducer,
  releaseReviewReducer,
  form: formReducer,
  logoutReducer,
  customAvatarReducer,
});
```

and this is the tree of the files,

[image]

The problem is that i get the error " you reach the maximum call stack size "

What am I doing wrong ? I don't know if could be this the problem but we are using Immutable.js

***UPDATE***

This is the error received 
[image]

and this is the index file right now

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
import appReducer from './appReducer';
import errorReducer from './errorReducer';
import loginReducer from './loginReducer';
import modalReducer from './modalReducer';
import changeRequestReducer from './changeRequestReducer';
import releaseReducer from './releaseReducer';
import releaseReviewReducer from './releaseReviewReducer';
import logoutReducer from './logoutReducer';
import customAvatarReducer from './customAvatarReducer';
import { USER_LOGOUT } from '../actions/logoutActions';

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === USER_LOGOUT) {
    const state = undefined;
  }

  return reducers(state, action);
};

const reducers = combineReducers({
  appReducer,
  errorReducer,
  loginReducer,
  changeRequestReducer,
  releaseReducer,
  modalReducer,
  releaseReviewReducer,
  form: formReducer,
  logoutReducer,
  customAvatarReducer,
  rootReducer,
});

export default reducers;
```

Comment: this error is usually caused by you calling a function recursively with no exit condition

Comment: Thank you David for your comment and your time. Should I post more code to help you to understand what's going on? If yes, what section would be helpful ?

Comment: does the error have a line number associated?  If so, please post the code relevant to that line.

Comment: what are you trying to do inside the rootReducer function? As far as I know reducers should return state

Comment: i just tried to followed the answer of Dan abramov in the link, but i don't really know how to implement it.

Comment: have you tried to rename your `reducers` object to something else, `myReducers` for example?

Comment: yup, but nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
export default reducers;
```

to

```
export default rootReducer;
```

Answer (score 0):

you only have to replace bit lines , try with below code.

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === USER_LOGOUT) {
    state = [];
  }

  return reducers(...state, action);
};
```

Comment: No, the state is still full, but at least i don't have the error of the max stack, plus the state is not iterable, i can post the error screen XD i going mad, really.

Comment: try it with `state=undefined` or `state=Immutable.Map()` since https://github.com/gajus/redux-immutable#usage

Comment: if you return reducer like this , then you get empty state(store)
{
return reducers(state, action);
}

Comment: @vijay sadhu, that's what Legeo wants, to reset/clear the state.