# Encountering argument TypeError when calling createStore with rootReducer

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, react-redux

I've recently implemented a logout action for my Redux store, following the suggestion provided by Dan here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/11980562

However, now that I've separated my reducer into a `rootReducer` and an `appReducer`, my `createStore` is throwing the following error:

```
Argument of type '(state: { activity: ActivityState; asyncActions: AsyncActionState; tasks: TaskState; userInfo: UserInfoState; }, action: RootAction) => { activity: ActivityState; asyncActions: AsyncActionState; tasks: TaskState; userInfo: UserInfoState; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Reducer<{ activity: ActivityState; asyncActions: AsyncActionState; tasks: TaskState; userInfo: UserInfoState; }, RootAction>'.\n  Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.\n    Type '{ activity: ActivityState; asyncActions: AsyncActionState; tasks: TaskState; userInfo: UserInfoState; } | undefined' is not assignable to type '{ activity: ActivityState; asyncActions: AsyncActionState; tasks: TaskState; userInfo: UserInfoState; }'.\n      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type '{ activity: ActivityState; asyncActions: AsyncActionState; tasks: TaskState; userInfo: UserInfoState; }
```

```
// reducers/index.ts
const initialRootState: RootState = {
  activity: initialActivityState,
  asyncActions: {},
  tasks: initialTaskState,
  userInfo: initialUserState
};

export const appReducer = combineReducers({
  activity: activityReducer,
  asyncActions: asyncActionReducer,
  tasks: tasksReducer,
  userInfo: userReducer
});

export default (state: RootState, action: RootAction) => {
  return appReducer(
    action.type === LogoutActionType ? initialRootState : state,
    action
  );
};

// store/index.ts
export const store = createStore(rootReducer, initialState, enhancers);
```

I can't quite figure out why the introduction of this new behavior is causing the state to be potentially undefined.

I also noticed that the same error persists when the `rootReducer` simply calls the `appReducer`, without the new `LogoutActionType` behavior:

```
export default (state: RootState, action: RootAction) => {
  return appReducer(
    state,
    action
  );
};
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to the [official type definition](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux/blob/9c9a4d2a1c62c9dbddcbb05488f8bd77d24c81de/index.d.ts#L102), A function of `Reducer` type should accept undefined as the first parameter, which is not the case for your exported function.

The reason why you did not encounter this error when writing the individual reducers, is most likely that they are of the following form:

```
function subReducer(state: SubState = { dummy: '1' }, action: any) {
  return state;
}
```

The first parameter comes with a default value, which also changes the type signature of the function from `(state: SubState, action: any)` to `(state: SubState | undefined, action: any)`.

If there is no default value for the first parameter, you have to manually change its type declaration, adding an `undefined` to form a union type.