# How to reset state of Redux Store when using configureStore from @reduxjs/toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have seen solutions for clearing/resetting the store after logout but did not understand how to implement the same functionality for the following way of setting up the redux store.

**Store.js:**

```
import { configureStore, getDefaultMiddleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import authReducer from './ducks/authentication'
import snackbar from './ducks/snackbar'
import sidebar from './ducks/sidebar'
import global from './ducks/global'
import quickView from './ducks/quickView'
import profileView from './ducks/profileView'

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    auth: authReducer,
    snackbar,
    sidebar,
    global,
    quickView,
    profileView,
  },
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware()],
})

export default store
```

Here is how all the reducers implemented using createAction and createReducer from @reduxjs/toolkit.

**snackbar.js:**

```
import { createAction, createReducer } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'

export const handleSnackbar = createAction('snackbar/handleSnackbar')

export const openSnackBar = (
  verticalPosition,
  horizontalPosition,
  message,
  messageType,
  autoHideDuration = 10000
) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    dispatch(
      handleSnackbar({
        verticalPosition,
        horizontalPosition,
        message,
        autoHideDuration,
        messageType,
        isOpen: true,
      })
    )
  }
}

export const closeSnackbar = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(handleSnackbar({ isOpen: false }))
  }
}

const initialState = {
  verticalPosition: 'bottom',
  horizontalPosition: 'center',
  message: '',
  autoHideDuration: 6000,
  isOpen: false,
  messageType: 'success',
}

export default createReducer(initialState, {
  [handleSnackbar]: (state, action) => {
    const {
      isOpen,
      verticalPosition,
      horizontalPosition,
      message,
      autoHideDuration,
      messageType,
    } = action.payload
    state.isOpen = isOpen
    state.verticalPosition = verticalPosition
    state.horizontalPosition = horizontalPosition
    state.message = message
    state.autoHideDuration = autoHideDuration
    state.messageType = messageType
  },
})
```

Comment: You dispatch a thunk action that dispatches a reset() action to every reducer, triggering them to return their initial state.

Comment: Hi @timotgl, Thank you very much for the response. Can you please share an example snippet? That would be really helpful.

Comment: See answer below

Comment: See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73372455/10030693

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simplified example with two reducers:

```
// actions and reducer for state.first
const resetFirst = () => ({ type: 'FIRST/RESET' });

const firstReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // other action types here

        case 'FIRST/RESET':
            return initialState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};


// actions and reducer for state.second
const resetSecond = () => ({ type: 'SECOND/RESET' });

const secondReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        // other action types here

        case 'SECOND/RESET':
            return initialState;

        default:
            return state;
    }
};


const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    first: firstReducer,
    second: secondReducer
});

// thunk action to do global logout
const logout = () => (dispatch) => {
    // do other logout stuff here, for example logging out user with backend, etc..

    dispatch(resetFirst());
    dispatch(resetSecond());
    // Let every one of your reducers reset here.
};
```

Answer (score 66):

As per [Dan Abramov's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/2873538), create a **root reducer** which will simply delegate the *action* to your **main or combined reducer**. And whenever this root reducer receives a **reset** type of action, it resets the state.

**Example:**

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  first: firstReducer,
  second: secondReducer,
  // ... all your app's reducers
})

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'RESET') {
    state = undefined
  }
  return combinedReducer(state, action)
}
```

So, if you have configured your store with [@reduxjs/toolkit's configureStore](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore), it might look like this:

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import counterReducer from '../features/counter/counterSlice';

export default configureStore({
  reducer: {
    counter: counterReducer,
    // ... more reducers
  },
});
```

where `configureStore`'s first parameter `reducer` accepts a **function** (which is treated as root reducer) or an **object** of [`slice`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice) reducers which is internally converted to *root reducer* using [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers).

So, now instead of passing object of slice reducers (shown above), we can create and pass root reducer by ourselves, here is how we can do it:

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer,
  // ... more reducers
});
```

Now, lets create a root reducer which does our **reset** job when needed:

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'counter/logout') { // check for action type 
    state = undefined;
  }
  return combinedReducer(state, action);
};

export default configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [...getDefaultMiddleware()]
});
```

Here is [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-state-redux-toolkit-p515y?file=/src/store.ts)

Comment: This answer should be in the docs of redux-toolkit, thnks! P.S: take a look at the CodeSandbox implementation, Ajeet added more comments there.

Comment: Any chance of a TypeScript version of the CodeSandbox with types?

Comment: @Jamie The sandbox link in my answer is a Typescript version. What types are you looking at? Or what exactly is your question? If you have a different question, feel free to ask a new question and you may post the link here in comment.

Comment: I forked your sandbox and added types- you can view that [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-state-redux-toolkit-forked-u17iv), you can also see my answer below.

Comment: I wanted to know when and how this action of logout is going to be called.

Comparing `action.type === "counter/logout"`. Does this mean that state will be undefined every-time logout function defined inside counter slice is going to be called. If so, do we need to create this `logout` reducer function in all our states.

Also in codesandbox, there is no code inside the logout reducer of counter slice. So i couldn't understand what is going on.

@AjeetShah

Comment: @AakashSharma `Does this mean that state will be undefined every-time logout function defined inside counter slice is going to be called?` : Yes. `do we need to create this logout reducer function in all our states`: No. `there is no code inside the logout reducer of counter slice`: yes, it is empty because I wanted to handle it at `rootReducer`. We just need one logout action. We can create that action in just one slice and handle that at root reducer.

Comment: It works. but seems pretty clunky that we have to create reducer to handle an event that is not actually handled by said reducer :/

Answer (score 26):

I wanted to extend Ajeet's answer so that it is accessible to those who want complete type safety throughout their Redux store.

The key differences are that you need to declare a `RootState` type, which is documented [in the RTK docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-with-typescript#getting-the-state-type)

```
const combinedReducer = combineReducers({
  counter: counterReducer
});

export type RootState = ReturnType<typeof combinedReducer>;
```

And then in your rootReducer, where you are executing your `logout` function, you want to maintain type safety all the way down by giving the `state` param the `RootState` type, and `action` param `AnyAction`.

The final piece of the puzzle is setting your state to an empty object of type `RootState` instead of `undefined`.

```
const rootReducer: Reducer = (state: RootState, action: AnyAction) => {
  if (action.type === "counter/logout") {
    state = {} as RootState;
  }
  return combinedReducer(state, action);
};
```

I forked Ajeet's answer on CodeSandbox, added the required types, and you can view it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reset-state-redux-toolkit-forked-u17iv).

Comment: Thank you for this! Saved me hours of debugging type problems lol

Comment: Thx for complete solution! Looks like it can be an accepted answer.

Answer (score 15):

If you're looking to reset each slice to its initial state (unlike setting the entire state to an empty object) you can use [extraReducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers) to respond to a `logout` action and return the initial state.

In auth.tsx:

```js
const logout = createAction('auth/logout')
```

In foo.tsx:

```js
const initialState = {
  bar: false,
}

const fooSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'foo',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(logout, () => {
      return initialState
    })
  },
})
```

Comment: this was preferred approach for me

Comment: For me as well, because: (1) this will set the state to the initial state, not an undefined state; (2) this avoids the switch on action.type, which is normally not present in the 'new way' of doing it with redux toolkit

Comment: I'm using this in combination with the `resetApiState` [action](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/api-slice-utils#resetapistate) for resetting RTK Query.

Comment: I think this could just go in the normal reducer object i.e. `reducers { resetState: () => initialState }` + `export const { resetState } = fooSlice.actions`

Comment: The problem with this approach, is that this would only reset the "foo" namespaced reducer data.

Comment: Why are we using `extraReducers` here? The same can be achieved using normal reducers. Note that we don't do `state = initialState` but `return initialState`. This has something to do with immer library that is used in RTK.

Comment: @blwinters whereabouts did you put the resetApiState? Trying to work out the best place it should happen

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution - just add a reducer like this...

```
    resetList: (state) => {
      return (state = []);
    },
```

... and call it with a button:

```
  const handleResetList = () => {
    dispatch(resetList());
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>List</div>
      <button onClick={handleResetList}>Reset</button>
```