# Reset state to initial with redux-toolkit

Tags: javascript, redux, redux-toolkit

I need to reset current state to initial state. But
all my attempts were unsuccessful. How can I do it using redux-toolkit?

```js
const showOnReviewSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'showOnReview',
  initialState: {
    returned: [],
  },
  reducers: {
    reset(state) {
      //here I need to reset state of current slice
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: @AjeetShah perfect solution, thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
const intialState = {
  returned: []
}

const showOnReviewSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'showOnReview',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: () => initialState
    }
});
```

Comment: yes, it works. Also correct is reset() {return initialState} or reset: () => initialState

Comment: I thought just setting `state = initialState` would suffice because in other examples, we only need to mutate `state`. Alas, resetting the state needed a different approach :/

Comment: I must admin that even redux-toolkit is awesome it is littlebit immutability dark-magic :D Btw `return { ...initialState }` also works...

Comment: Thanks for the tip. Returning the value did it. I wasted some time by assigning initialState to the state by assuming that immer would do the magic underneath!

Comment: Year later got the notification, which made me curious if my answer became obsolete :)
I have prepared a small demo which clearly shows that provided answer is still perfectly valid and works with the latest redux-toolkit, please check it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/initial-state-redux-toolkit-12d1-9lpu7?file=/src/features/counterSlice.js

Comment: @dorklord yeah, *why* isn't `state = initialstate` sufficient?

Comment: Also the `state => initialState `doesn't need the `state` in it. As the second answer shows, `() => initialState` suffices

Comment: @Dorklord `state = initialState` doesn't work because you are changing the reference and redux toolkit has no way of knowing that as it keeps the old reference. You must **either** mutate the original `state` **OR** *return* new object. @nachtigall @fullStackChris

Comment: @Baterka `return { ...initialState }` is unnecessary and perhaps you come from traditional redux where mutation was forbidden. Here `return initialState` and `return { ...initialState }` are equivalent.

Answer (score 21):

When using multiple slices, all slices can be reverted to their initial state using [extraReducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers).

First, create an action that can be used by all slices:

```js
export const revertAll = createAction('REVERT_ALL')
```

In every slice add an `initialState`, and an `extraReducers` reducer using the `revertAll` action:

```js
const initialState = {};
export const someSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'something',
  initialState,
  extraReducers: (builder) => builder.addCase(revertAll, () => initialState),
  reducers: {}
});
```

The store can be created as usual:

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    someReducer: someSlice.reducer,
  }
})
```

And in your react code you can call the `revertAll` action with the `useDispatch` hook:

```js
export function SomeComponent() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return <span onClick={() => dispatch(revertAll())}>Reset</span>
}
```

Comment: Wow! That's what I've been looking for!

Comment: This code works though we need to add repititive code in all the reducers. Wish there was a more elegant way to achieve without duplication  of code

Comment: Thanks! Suggestions on removing the repetition are welcome

Comment: This is the only way worked in 2023. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Blee. Please I need clarification on how to do the dispatch. Since we have the rever All on all slices. How do I combine all before dispatching?

Comment: That is what `extraReducers` do: they allow all the slices to respond to the same action. The dispatch works like any other dispatch, but now it triggers multiple reducers.

Comment: This is the best way in 2023. Thanks mate, you saved my day

Comment: This results in `typeOrActionCreator is undefined` for me

Answer (score 18):

This worked for me (mid-late 2020). Formatted with your code context as an example.

```js
const initialState = {
  returned: [],
};

const showOnReviewSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'showOnReview',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset: () => initialState,
  },
});
```

Comment: None of these worked for me :( it just says initialState is not defined. My bad forgot to define the initialstate

Comment: This is the better styled answer.

Answer (score 13):

Replacing `state` with `initialState` directly did *not* work for me (mid 2020).  What I finally got working was to copy each property over with `Object.assign()`.  This worked:

```
const showOnReviewSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'showOnReview',
    initialState: {
        returned: []
    },
    reducers: {
        reset(state) {
            Object.assign(state, initialState)
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please answer my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63885139/how-to-get-a-state-value-in-the-reducer-of-createslice-in-redux-toolkit

Comment: Thank you sm! Nothing else worked for me!

Answer (score 9):

We do it like this guys.

Suppose you want to clear all the data at the point of logging out.

In your store.tsx file:

```
import { AnyAction, combineReducers, configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import authReducer from './slices/authSlice'
import messageReducer from './slices/messageSlice'



const appReducer = combineReducers({
  auth: authReducer,
  message: messageReducer,
});

const reducerProxy = (state: any, action: AnyAction) => {
  if(action.type === 'logout/LOGOUT') {
    return appReducer(undefined, action);
  }
  return appReducer(state, action);
}

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: reducerProxy,
});
```

Then you create a thunk like this:

```
export const logout = createAsyncThunk(
    "auth/logout",
    async function (_payload, thunkAPI) {
        thunkAPI.dispatch({ type: 'logout/LOGOUT' });
        console.log('logged out')
    }
);
```

After you've dispatched the logout thunk, you can also refresh the browser so it auto-redirects the user to the login page.

```
function MyReactComponent() {
   const dispatch = useDispatch()

   function myLogoutOnClickHandler() {
      dispatch(logout())
      window.location = window.location;
   }
   ...

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In my case, as the previous answer, mid 2021, just setting the initial state **DO NOT WORK,** even if you use the toolkit adapter like :

```
reducers: {
        // Other reducers
         state = tasksAdapter.getInitialState({
                status: 'idle',
                error: null,
                current: null
            })
        }
    },
```

instead, you should use `Object.assign()`, guess that it's related with the internal immer library behavior

Comment: You're right. In v1.5.0 you have to get it done with `Object.assign(state, initialState)`

Answer (score 3):

Try this. In my case, I wanted to return **all slices to initialState** when a certain action is dispatched.

- First, let's create action:

```
import { createAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const resetPanelsAction = createAction('resetPanelsData');
```

- When creating our store, we save a copy of the initialState in the middleware:

```
import { Middleware } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const resetDataMiddleware: Middleware =
    ({ getState }) =>
    (next) => {
        // "Caching" our initial app state
        const initialAppState = getState();

        return (action) => {
            // Let's add the condition that if the action is of 
            // type resetData, then add our cached state to its payload
            if (action.type === 'resetData') {
                const actionWithInitialAppState = {
                    ...action,
                    payload: initialAppState,
                };

                return next(actionWithInitialAppState);
            }

            return next(action);
        };
    };
```

- Almost done! Now let's change our root reducer a little by adding a wrapper that will check the action type, and if it is equal to resetData, then return `combinedReducers` with our **initialState**, which will be in payload.

```
import { AnyAction } from 'redux';
import { combineReducers } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

export const combinedReducers = combineReducers({
    /** Your reducers */
});

export const rootReducer = (
    state: ReturnType<typeof combinedReducers> | undefined,
    action: AnyAction,
) => {
    if (action.type === 'resetPanelsData') {
        return combinedReducers(action.payload, action);
    }

    return combinedReducers(state, action);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use spread opearator for `initialState`

```
const initialState: {
  returned: unknown[] //set your type here
} = {
  returned: []
}

const showOnReviewSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'showOnReview',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    reset() {
      return {
        ...initialState
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also reset and change some initial parameters like this:

```
const intialState = {
  name: "",
  surname: "",
}

const showOnReviewSlice = createSlice({
    name: 'showOnReview',
    initialState,
    reducers: {
        reset: () => initialState, ...initialState.name = "Example"
    }
});
```