# How to reset Redux Reducer to Initial State

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, redux

How to reset a specific Redux Reducer to initial state
Is it possible to reset it to initial state?
I want when leave the register page, like go to Home or other pages the state of the register reducer back to initial state in React Native...

```
const initialState = {
  registerLoading: false,
  registerResult: null,
  registerError: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTER_USER_ACTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        registerLoading: action.payload.loading,
        registerResult: action.payload.data,
        registerError: action.payload.errorMessage,
      };    
     default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can simply return the initial state when the relevant action occurs.

Comment: If you respected the rule of not mutating the state but always replacing it with an updated version, of course you can: you simply need to `return { ...initialState }` when the desired action occurs.

Comment: For redux toolkit, See answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73372455/10030693

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to dispatch an action when you leave the page, e.g. action.type = RESET_INITIAL_STATE.

Create the case in your switch statement for it:

```
const initialState = {
  registerLoading: false,
  registerResult: null,
  registerError: null,
};

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case REGISTER_USER_ACTION:
      return {
        ...state,
        registerLoading: action.payload.loading,
        registerResult: action.payload.data,
        registerError: action.payload.errorMessage,
      }; 
    case RESET_INITIAL_STATE:
      return {
        ...initialState,
      };   
     default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for advice, btw where should i put the dispatch?, in the Register Page or other pages? and put it inside useEffect or where?

Comment: The best place is probably in componentWillUnmount or the useEffect equivalent (in the return statement of useEffect)

Comment: Okay, its work like i want by putting dispatch RESET_INITIAL_STATE inside the useEffect