# Best way to reset the nested state with using combine reducer in redux-toolkit

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, redux-toolkit

let say I have my store with nested combineReducers as below

```
const rootReducer = () =>
  combineReducers({
    agent,
    customer: customerReducer
  });

const customerReducer = combineReducer({
  profile,
  account
})
```

In this case if I want to reset the full customer state to its initial state how can I do that?

Note:

```
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.3.5",
"typescript": "^3.8.3"
```

Comment: Hi Sunil, welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you add what you've tried so far in the above post?

Answer (score 2):

#### Store Configuration:

Assuming this is how your store is **configured** using [reduxjs/toolkit](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/configureStore):

```
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer,
  middleware: [
    ...getDefaultMiddleware(),
  ],
})

export default store
```

where the `rootReducer` is:

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  agent: agentReducer,
  customer: customerReducer
});
```

And where `customerReducer` is **nested**, i.e. *combination of two* other reducers:

```
const customerReducer = combineReducer({
  profile,
  account
})
```

## Answer:

To **reset** only `customer` state in your Redux Store, you need to create a **wrapper** reducer which will simply delegate the action to your `customerReducer` and whenever this wrapper reducer receives a `CUSTOMER/RESET` type of action, it **resets the customer state**:

```
const customerReducerWrapper = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'CUSTOMER/RESET') {
    state = undefined
  }
  return customerReducer(state, action)
}

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  agent: agentReducer,
  customer: customerReducerWrapper
});
```

See: [How to reset redux state](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61943631/2873538)?

Comment: Thank you that helped.