# Redux-Persist - Can't reset state completely

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, local-storage, redux-persist

I'm using redux-persist in my react app. On logout, I want to completely reset the redux state and remove all local storage data.

This is my logout action, in which I delete the refresh token from the backend and then call purge on the redux store persistor before dispatching a RESET.

```
export const logout = () => (dispatch) => {
    if (localStorage.refreshToken) {
        axios.post(`${API_URL}/logout`, {token: localStorage.refreshToken}).then( async () => {
            // rest redux-persist
            await persistor.purge();
            dispatch({ type: RESET });
        });
    }
}
```

In my root reducer, I followed [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/6704320) to handle this RESET action:

```
const appReducer = combineReducers({
    /* app level reducers...*/
});

const rootReducer =  (state, action) => {
    console.log("Reducing action: ", action);
    if (action.type === RESET) {
        // reset state
        state = undefined;
        // reset local storage
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    return appReducer(state, action)
}

export default rootReducer;
```

I can see that my tokens are cleared from local storage and also that the last triggered action is indeed the RESET action. But still the local storage contains the `persist:root` from redux-persist. Does anybody know why it isn't removed or how I can achieve what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store)

Comment: @RameshRajendran no, I even linked that post in my question above.

Comment: did you got the solution for this..??

Comment: did u get solution for this??

Comment: The question is why do you want to remove the entry completely? If the correct action is fired then the local storage is indeed cleared but soon after that redux-persist rehydrates it all over again with initial data so why can't you work with just that?.

Comment: ` persistor.purge().then(() => {
    persistor.flush();
    persistor.pause();
    persistor.persist();
  });` Only this worked for me