# Update a specific property in each object in redux state

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

I want to update a specific property in each object in redux state, and assume I have this kind of main state

```
networkFailure: true
employer: {
  signUp: {
    data: null
    error: null
    loading: true
  }
}
user: {
  signUp: {
    data: null
    error: null
    loading: false
  }
}
```

Assume I have faced to a network failure, then the **networkFailure** state becomes **true** , and with that I need to fail(false) loading **signUp** state of the **employer** and all loading status to the **false** value of other objects too

Is that possible to do this in one reducer? or any suggestions for do it in a better way?
I have setup 3 reducer functions for employer, user and network

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One answer is found from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/1390894)

Actually when a network failure happened, for me it is fine to reset the application state,

So I have reset the application state in the root reducer

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'NETWORK_ERROR') {
    state = undefined
  }
  return appReducer(state, action)
}
```

this will keep other reducer's state to its default one

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways as I think:
1. Using the redux-thunk and dispatch an action and then dispatch 3 actions inside the action function which return dispatch function to you.something like this:

```js
function setErrorAction() {
  return dispatch => {
      const networkError = {type: "network/singup/error"}
      const employer Error = {type: "employer/singup/error"}
      const userError = {type: "user/singup/error"}

      dispatch(networkError)
      dispatch(employer)
      dispatch(userError)
  }
}
```

2. Write a hook function that it has access to the dispatch function which exposed function to dispatch actions that when you call the hook function, it will dispatch actions to the reducers but it is a way to centralizing the business. something like this:

```
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";

function useAuthError() {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

   function setError() {
      const networkError = {type: "network/singup/error"}
      const employer Error = {type: "employer/singup/error"}
      const userError = {type: "user/singup/error"}

      dispatch(networkError)
      dispatch(employer)
      dispatch(userError)
   };

   return {
      setError
   }
}
```

Comment: This is a good solution, but dispatching multiple actions is not good for this kind of thing, lets say I have 10 more states then I have to dispatch 10 actions

Comment: you're right, but redux can't update multiple reducers by one action, you know, redux doesn't have this feature.