# DevSettings.reload() for logout in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, react-native-bridge

### The Problem

I am migrating the logout functionality of my hybrid app from native to react native.

Requirements:

- It works in production and on a device
- It navigates to the root screen of the app (login screen)
- It clears the redux store
- [nice to have] It cancels any in-flight requests

Initially, we planned to do something like this: [how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/2423416)

### The Idea

As of React Native 0.62.0, we now have access to the DevSettings module. DevSettings has a native bridge that can [reload](https://reactnative.dev/docs/devsettings#reload) the react-native environment. But are DevSettings really only for development environments?

> Export the DevSettings module, add addMenuItem method (cc068b0551 by
> @janicduplessis)

### The Question

1. What are the tradeoffs for using reload vs logging out with a redux action?
2. Should I use reload in a production app?

### Edit: The Answer

1. Reload is disallowed in prod ([code](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0b9ea60b4fee8cacc36e7160e31b91fc114dbc0d/Libraries/Utilities/DevSettings.js#L59-L65))
2. [react-native-restart](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-restart) worked great for my use case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the line in code that disallows using devSettings in prod

```
import NativeDevSettings from '../NativeModules/specs/NativeDevSettings';
import NativeEventEmitter from '../EventEmitter/NativeEventEmitter';

class DevSettings extends NativeEventEmitter {
  ...
  reload(reason: string) {
    if (typeof NativeDevSettings.reloadWithReason === 'function') {
      NativeDevSettings.reloadWithReason(reason || 'Uncategorized from JS');
    } else {
      NativeDevSettings.reload();
    }
  }
  ...
}

// Avoid including the full `NativeDevSettings` class in prod.
class NoopDevSettings {
  addMenuItem(title: string, handler: () => mixed) {}
  reload() {}
}

module.exports = __DEV__ ? new DevSettings() : new NoopDevSettings();
```

from [Libraries/Utilities/DevSettings](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0b9ea60b4fee8cacc36e7160e31b91fc114dbc0d/Libraries/Utilities/DevSettings.js#L59-L65)

Answer (score 1):

> The DevSettings module exposes methods for customizing settings for
>   developers **in development**.

The `DevSettings` is for development environment only, it will not work in release mode.
The best solution is to follow the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store/35641992#35641992) you shared in your question

Comment: Ah yes, I read that in the docs but the docs are pretty sparse. Why is it only in development? Does it enforce it can only be used in development?

Comment: It's just a new way to reload your app with a user interaction but it's not a possibility to reload an app in release

Comment: Can you elaborate? Where in the code does it say it is not possible? edit: found something https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0b9ea60b4fee8cacc36e7160e31b91fc114dbc0d/Libraries/Utilities/DevSettings.js#L59-L65