# NativeModules.DevSettings.reload() is not working in build version

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, ecmascript-2016

I am struggling to reload the screen in React Native. In dev it working fine , I am achieving my goal but when I build android version and install it on my phone then `NativeModules.DevSettings.reload()` is not working in build version . Could someone please help me how to achieve my goal .

Thanks

**Code**

```
NativeModules.DevSettings.reload()
```

Comment: Have you found any way to deal with it ? If any please share.

Comment: Here is a related issue and please checkout the answers
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61392596/devsettings-reload-for-logout-in-react-native