# Redux state isn't being updated across the app in development

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

I'm having a very weird issue with redux. In my current app, I decided to use a logout pattern [suggested by Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/8753992).

Basically, it looks like this:

```
const withLogout = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === UserActions.logout.toString()) {
    state = undefined
  }
  return rootReducer(state, action)
}
```

The state is getting purged after the logout action is dispatched. I added logs to reducers and they all show that the state is getting reset to a default value. React Native Debugger shows the same thing.

However, the state inside the `connect`(`react-redux`) functions doesn't change. Even weirder, it looks like the function detects the fact that the state has changed because the logger function in `mapState` is being triggered. But the logger's output shows that the state hasn't changed there. Components are also not getting updated.

And as I mentioned in the title this issue happens only in dev mode. As soon as I build the app and install it everything starts working as intended. And it isn't caused by Debugger.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason. I had to import the store in a couple of places where I couldn't use `react-redux` to dispatch the action. This led to require cycles which sometimes led to creating multiple instances of the store.

I stumbled upon the following solution that makes sure you're using the same instance of the store across the app: instead of importing store in several places use the following pattern:

```
    // somewhere in the code
    let store
    export const setStore = storeInstance => store = storeInstance 
    ...
    store.dispatch()

    // store index.js
    import { setStore } from 'someplace'
    ...
    setStore(store)
```