# Logging old user data on login after logout in react using JWT

Tags: node.js, reactjs, redux, jwt

I am using react node js with SQL.
When I logout from reactJS I am removing the token while logging out. But still when i login within different credentials it takes me to dashboard with old user data and when I refresh page i get the data with new currently logged in user.

What could be it
The code part is pretty much correct I guess because it shows perfect data after page refresh.

my logout action

```
export const logoutAction = () => {
    return dispatch => {
        localStorage.removeItem('tkn')
        dispatch({ type: LOGOUT, payload: "" })
    }
}
```

logout reducer

```
case LOGOUT:
        return {
            ...state,
            token: action.payload,
            isAuth: false,
        }
```

Triggered action from the navbar

```
  const logout = () => {
    props.logoutUser()
    handleDrawerClose()
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "old user data", old username? any data on page from previous session?

Comment: show the code of data that needs to be refreshed with the new login.

Comment: yes data for different userID and login  credentials @Kerematam

Comment: Your question does not have enough info to clarify the issue, The most probable reason to me seems to be not updating the state properly.

Comment: `Axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/shopuser/order/orders', {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
 })
            .then((resp) => {
                dispatch({ type: CURRENT_ORDERS_FETCH, payload: resp.data.orders })
            })`

fetching this API 
headers

Comment: but after page refresh its working fine @Ashu

Comment: reset whole state duing authentication : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store

Comment: I guess this is the solution which  I was looking for @Kerematam

Answer (score 0):

I Had the same problem. My APP get a JWT auth token from a ASP.NET Web API and use this for display some items after login. But when the user loggout and other user does login, the data from the first user apear instead off the last user data.
I found a session cookie and I resolved the problem installing the react-native-cookies package (@react-native-cookies/cookies). https://github.com/react-native-cookies/cookies

```
yarn add @react-native-cookies/cookies
```

After this, on my AuthActions, on my Logout routine, I call clearAll() method.

```
import CookieManager from '@react-native-cookies/cookies';

export const userLogout = () => {
  CookieManager.clearAll();

  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch({type: LOGOUT_ACTION});
    // more actions...
  };
};
```