# How to reset the state of a Redux store using connected-react-router?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, connected-react-router

I'm trying to acheive this exact same behaviour [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store). except I'm using connected-react-router. My Configuration looks like this:

Reducer

```
export const rootReducer = history => combineReducers({
    auth: auth.reducer,
    router: connectRouter(history),
    authentication: authenticationReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
    project: projectReducer,
    domain: domainReducer,
    test: testReducer
});
```

Store

```
export const history = createBrowserHistory({ basename: '/metro' });

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const middleware = [
  ...getDefaultMiddleware({
    immutableCheck: false,
    serializableCheck: false,
    thunk: true
  }),
  sagaMiddleware,
  routerMiddleware(history)
];

const store = configureStore({
  reducer: rootReducer(history),
  middleware,
  devTools: process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production",
  enhancers: [reduxBatch]
});
```

I tried, but does not work:

```
const appReducer = (state, action, history) => combineReducers({
    auth: auth.reducer,
    router: connectRouter(history),
    authentication: authenticationReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
    project: projectReducer,
    domain: domainReducer,
    test: testReducer
})

export const rootReducer = history => (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === actionTypes.LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
        state = undefined;
    }
    return appReducer(state, action, history)
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a [known issue](https://github.com/supasate/connected-react-router/issues/178) with this package. The solution seems to be setting the state to an `initialState` value, instead of `undefined`. The only caveat is that you shouldn't try to re-initialize the `router`–it should do this by default.

```
const appReducer = (state, action, history) => combineReducers({
    auth: auth.reducer,
    router: connectRouter(history),
    authentication: authenticationReducer,
    users: usersReducer,
    project: projectReducer,
    domain: domainReducer,
    test: testReducer
})

const initialState = {
    // Don't reset router here
    auth: {},
    authentication: {},
    users: {},
    project: {},
    domain: {},
    test: {}
}

export const rootReducer = history => (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === actionTypes.LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
        state = initialState;
    }
    return appReducer(state, action, history)
};
```

Comment: Thanks very much. the link also helped I changed the return to return appReducer(history)(state, action); and now it works. I really appreciate your help.