# Why is Redux-Persist not persisting the store

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-persist

Hi there everyone I was messing around with react(redux to be precise) and came across a problem. When I refresh the page redux store does as well everything returns to its initial value, I googled the problem and found out that I have to use `redux-persist`. However even that is not working, I think the problem is with how I configured redux-persist but I could be wrong.
The code below is how I went about the redux-persist configuration.

```
// configureStore.js

import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from "redux";
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from "redux-persist";
import storage from "redux-persist/lib/storage";
import rootReducer from "../reducers/index";

import { composeWithDevTools } from "redux-devtools-extension";
import thunk from "redux-thunk";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
);

export const persistedStore = persistStore(store);
```

The code below shows how I went about making the `rootReducer`.

```
// index.js
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { reducer as formReducer } from "redux-form";

import authReducer from "./auth";
import messageReducer from "./message";
import chatroomReducer from "./chatroom";

import { LOGOUT_SUCCESS } from "../actions/authTypes";

const apiReducer = combineReducers({
  authReducer,
  messageReducer,
  chatroomReducer,
  form: formReducer,
});

const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
    state = undefined;
  }
  return apiReducer(state, action);
};

export default rootReducer;
```

And the code below is the `index.js` that comes when creating the react app.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "./index.css";
import App from "./App";
import reportWebVitals from "./reportWebVitals";

import { PersistGate } from "redux-persist/integration/react";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";

import { store, persistedStore } from "./Redux/configureStore";

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistedStore}>
      <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
      </React.StrictMode>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? If you need additional info please let me know.

Comment: I am having the exact same issue. Were you able to fix this?

If i remove the `action.type === LOGOUT_SUCCESS` logic then it starts working. But I don't understand why that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the whitelist, where you must indicate which reducers to store.
Remember to import the reducers before adding them to the list

```html
import navigation from "./reducers/navigation";

// WHITELIST
const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: storage,
  whitelist: ['navigation'] // only navigation will be persisted
};
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I'm afraid even this is not working

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to import storage from Async

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
```

Use WhiteList like this

```
const persistConfig = {
   key: 'root',
   storage: AsyncStorage,
    whitelist: [
       'user'
    ],
  };
```

"user" is the specific root reducer you want to store

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion but I'm afraid even this is not working.

Answer (score 0):

As per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/6051241), you also need to clear out the `redux-persist` storage when you catch the `LOGOUT_SUCCESS` action.

First, you need to import the appropriate [storage engine](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist#storage-engines) and then clear it out completely.

```
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
    if (action.type === SIGNOUT_REQUEST) {
        // for all keys defined in your persistConfig(s)
        storage.removeItem('persist:root')
        // storage.removeItem('persist:otherKey')

        return appReducer(undefined, action);
    }
    return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a return statement in your conditional action: `action.type === LOGOUT_SUCCESS` (where you made the `rootReducer`):

Your code looks like this:

```js
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
    state = undefined;
  }
  return apiReducer(state, action);
};
```

Update it to:

```js
const rootReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === LOGOUT_SUCCESS) {
    return state = undefined;
  }
  return apiReducer(state, action);
};
```