# Delete or Reset redux thunk store completely while logout

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I am using `redux, react-redux and redux thunk` for `store` management in my react native project, there is deferent `reducers` and `actions`. How I `reset` the entire `store` during logout

Is there any methods like `createStore()` to destroy a store?
please share possible solutions

Thanks

Comment: You can create reducers what are restores the initial state, or if u are storing your state on AynscStorage and you can clear the state with key: persist:root.

Comment: Did you try to, well, refresh the page?

Comment: @kunquan yes tried,if call the api again then reseting the value but , if I am not calling api then I am getting the previous user data, I want to destroy the store during logout

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below solution worked for me,

```
import reduxReset from 'redux-reset'

const enHanceCreateStore = compose(
    applyMiddleware(thunk),
    reduxReset()  
  )(createStore)

const store = enHanceCreateStore(reducers)
```

dispatch reset action

```
store.dispatch({
  type: 'RESET'
})
```