# Clear the redux store after logout

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have created a redux store below, the only thing I want to clear the redux store when user logout from the application, so store having the latest and updated data of currently logged user.

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import storage from 'redux-persist/lib/storage';
import rootReducer from './Reducers';
import { sessionService } from 'redux-react-session';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const persistedReducer = persistReducer({ key: 'root', storage }, rootReducer);

const composeEnhancers =
  (typeof window !== 'undefined' &&
    window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) ||
  compose;

export const store = createStore(
  persistedReducer,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(thunk)
  )
);
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
sessionService.initSessionService(store);
```

The above snippet I wrote to create the store using `redux persist`
please suggest

Comment: You can just have an action for clearing the data and dispatch it in your logout function

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to reset the state of a Redux store?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35622588/how-to-reset-the-state-of-a-redux-store)

Answer (score 0):

you need to modify your `rootReducer` that u pass to `persistReducer`, where you put some action like `RESET`

code example (from your code)

```
import rootReducer from './Reducers';

const appReducer = (state, action) => {
  if (action.type === 'RESET') {
    return rootReducer(undefined, action)
  }

  return rootReducer(state, action)
}

const persistedReducer = persistReducer({ key: 'root', storage }, appReducer);
```

then you need to call that `RESET` action somewhere like that

```
store.dispatch({type: "RESET"})
```

`store` is from your `configureStore` or what you pass to `Provider` tag from `react-redux`, also persisted storage will be cleared too