# How to keep one redux slice from being cleared on logout?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have a React Native app (using TypeScript and Redux-Toolkit (RTK) Query) in which I want to show an intro slider only for the first app launch and never show it again unless the app data is cleared. I have created a slice for its `visibility` state and am using `redux-persist` to keep the data.

Upon logout I'm reseting the store and persisted state by following [Dan Abramov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35641992/16590740)'s and [Lenz Weber-Tronic](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/556#issuecomment-639154965)'s recommendations.

```js
// Root reducer (resettable)
const rootReducer = (
  state: ReturnType<typeof appReducer> | undefined,
  action: AnyAction
) => {
  // If the `logout` action is dispatched, clean the `Redux Persist` storage and reset the state
  if (action.type === "auth/logout") {
    storage.removeItem("persist:root");

    return appReducer(undefined, action);
  }

  return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

I also have separated the `persistence` config of my `intro` slice so that I can keep it into storage.

```js
// Root persistence config
const rootPersistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  version: 1,
  storage,
  blacklist: ["intro", api.reducerPath],
};

// Intro slides persistence config
const introPersistConfig = {
  key: "intro",
  version: 1,
  storage,
  blacklist: [api.reducerPath],
};
    
// Top-level reducers
const appReducer = combineReducers({
  [api.reducerPath]: api.reducer,
  auth: authSliceReducer,
  intro: persistReducer(introPersistConfig, introSliceReducer),
});
```

And this is the `intro` slice:

```js
interface IntroSliceState {
  /** Whether to show the app intro slides or not */
  showIntro: boolean;
}

const initialState: IntroSliceState = {
  showIntro: true,
};

const introSlice = createSlice({
  name: "intro",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    hideIntro: (state) => {
      state.showIntro = false;
    },
  },
});
```

The problem I'm trying to solve now is to find a way to keep the `intro` slice from being cleared on logout and I know I have to modify this part: `return appReducer(undefined, action);` but I have no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried clearing specific persistors?

```
storage.removeItem("persist:intro");
```

EDIT: Sorry just saw the blacklist. You should still try to single it out to rule out other possibilities

But I would probably recommend using a local storage for saving first time launch. There used to be AsyncStorage for react native but here are alternatives:

https://reactnative.directory/?search=storage

If you use expo, you could use:

@react-native-async-storage/async-storage

If you need an example of a first time launch hook + async storage helpers setup send a reply!

EDIT2:

useAppHasLaunched

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { getAsyncStorageItem, storeAsyncStorageItem } from '../utils/asyncStorageHelper'

export const useAppHasLaunched = () => {
  const HAS_LAUNCHED = 'HAS_LAUNCHED'

  const [hasLaunched, setHasLaunched] = useState<boolean>(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    getData()
  }, [])

  const getData = async () => {
    try {
      const hasLaunched = await getAsyncStorageItem(HAS_LAUNCHED)
      if (hasLaunched) {
        setHasLaunched(true)
      } else {
        await storeAsyncStorageItem(HAS_LAUNCHED, 'true')
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('ERROR_GET_LAUNCH_DATA', error)
    }
  }
  return { hasLaunched, setHasLaunched }
}
```

asyncStorageHelpers

```
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage'

export const getAsyncStorageItem = async (key: string) => {
  try {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(key)
    if (value) return value
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error getting data', error)
  }
  return false
}

export const storeAsyncStorageItem = async (key: string, value: string) => {
  try {
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(key, value)
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error storing data', error)
  }
}
```

Then I use it in my logged out screen:

```
const { hasLaunched, setHasLaunched } = useAppHasLaunched()
```

Render onboarding screen, pass in setHasLaunched and use it once your onboarding slider finishes or when you dismiss the slider

```
{!hasLaunched && <Onboarding setFinishedOnboarding={setHasLaunched} />}
```

Comment: This is indeed a good idea and might actually work (to isolate it from the redux ecosystem). I'd appreciate the example. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of passing undefined state to the reducer so the entire state tree is recomputed from initial state, compute a new state object with only what you want to keep retained.

Example:

```js
// Root reducer (resettable)
const rootReducer = (
  state: ReturnType<typeof appReducer> | undefined,
  action: AnyAction
) => {
  // If the `logout` action is dispatched, clean the `Redux Persist`
  // storage and reset the state
  if (action.type === "auth/logout") {
    storage.removeItem("persist:root"); // *

    // Keep intro state from previous state
    const { intro } = state;
    // Create new state with retain previous state values
    const nextState = {
      intro,
    };

    return appReducer(nextState, action);
  }

  return appReducer(state, action);
};
```

<sup>*</sup>Note: `storage.removeItem("persist:root");` is one way to delete the persisted state. Another is the [`persistor.purge`](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist/blob/master/docs/api.md#type-persistor) method to "clear out the stored state".

Note also that there may actually be no need to manually clear/purge the storage since upon logout and subsequent state update, the new state will be immediately persisted back out to storage.

Comment: Shouldn't the next state be `{...state, intro}`?

Comment: @Nima No, the idea is to keep only the previous state's `intro` value.

Comment: It does indeed work but unfortunately this gives this typescript error for the `nextState`: `Type '{ intro: (IntroSliceState & PersistPartial) | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type '{ api: CombinedState<{}, "Plates" | "Activities" | "Transactions", "api">; auth: AuthSliceState; intro: IntroSliceState & PersistPartial; }': api, auth`

Comment: @Nima I see, you may need to provide new initial values for these properties then. Alternatively you could also explicitly handle the `"auth/logout"` action in all reducers to reset their states independently.

Comment: Yeah the initial values would probably fix it but initializing the `Redux-Toolkit Query`'s `reducer` is making things quite complicated.

Comment: @Nima You could look in the Redux-Devtools and copy the root keys of the API slice and provide those initial values. You could also just persist the cached API slice state along with as well, e.g. keep `state.intro` and `state[api.reducerPath]` in the next state value.